# novnc for linux docker - x11vnc returns: XOpenDisplay failed (:0) *** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0"

Tags: linux, docker, x11vnc

I was following the steps from this link- [Kali In The Browser (noVNC)](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/novnc-kali-in-browser/)

I have installed kalilinux/kali-rolling on docker and running the commands. When I execute the command

```
x11vnc -display :0 -autoport -localhost -nopw -bg -xkb -ncache -ncache_cr -quiet -forever
```

I am getting the following error.

> 22/03/2022 11:10:08 ***************************************
> 22/03/2022 11:10:08 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)
>
> *** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.
>
> *** There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.
> Some tips and guidelines:
> ** An X server (the one you wish to view) must be running before x11vnc is started: x11vnc does not start the X server.  (however, see the -create option if that is what you really want). 
> ** You must use -display , -OR- set and export your $DISPLAY
> environment variable to refer to the display of the desired X server.
> - Usually the display is simply ":0" (in fact x11vnc uses this if you forget to specify it), but in some multi-user situations it could be ":1", ":2", or even ":137".  Ask your administrator or a guru if you are having difficulty determining what your X DISPLAY is.
> ** Next, you need to have sufficient permissions (Xauthority)
> to connect to the X DISPLAY.   Here are some Tips:
> - Often, you just need to run x11vnc as the user logged into the X session. 
> So make sure to be that user when you type x11vnc.
> - Being root is usually not enough because the incorrect MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE file may be accessed.  The cookie file contains the secret key that allows x11vnc to connect to the desired X DISPLAY.
> - You can explicitly indicate which MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE file should be used by the -auth option, e.g.:
> x11vnc -auth /home/someuser/.Xauthority -display :0
> x11vnc -auth /tmp/.gdmzndVlR -display :0you must have read permission for the auth file.
> See also '-auth guess' and '-findauth' discussed below.
>
> ** If NO ONE is logged into an X session yet, but there is a greeter login program like "gdm", "kdm", "xdm", or "dtlogin" running, you will need    to find and use the raw display manager MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE file. Some examples for various display managers:

```
 gdm:     -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth
          -auth /var/lib/gdm/:0.Xauth
 kdm:     -auth /var/lib/kdm/A:0-crWk72
          -auth /var/run/xauth/A:0-crWk72
 xdm:     -auth /var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/A:0-XQvaJk
 dtlogin: -auth /var/dt/A:0-UgaaXa
```

> Sometimes the command "ps wwwwaux | grep auth" can reveal the file location. Starting with `x11vnc 0.9.9` you can have it try to guess by using: `-auth guess` (see also the x11vnc -findauth option.)
>
> Only root will have read permission for the file, and so `x11vnc` must be run as root (or copy it).  The random characters in the filenames will of course change and the directory the cookie file resides in is system dependent.

See also: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html

[image]

[image]

From this, I will get the answer - https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/x11vnc-at-startup-4175414461/.
But I can't understand what they saying

Comment: Do you have x-server and xorg installed

Comment: no, i am new to docker I will install that first I used " apt install xorg "

Comment: Install xorg to get x-server its one and the same thing

Comment: I have installed and run this systemctl status xorg but getting this error systemctl status xorg
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Comment: Please share your docker file

Comment: docker run -ti -d --publish-all --privileged=true kalilinux/kali-rolling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134967/discussion-between-rahul-and-david-kariuki).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Your x-server is not running or probably not installed

Install it

```
apt-get install xorg
```

You will also have to install gdm3

```
apt-get install gdm3
```

You will then have to disable wayland by editing the file `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`. You can do this manually using your file explorer or using the below commmands depending on which text editors you have installed. E.g., using leafpad or gedit. (Try any of the two below)

```
leafpad /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf
gedit /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf
```

Then uncomment the line `WaylandEnable=false` by removing the `#` before it. Save the file.

Run

```
dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

The command `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` will cause gdm to reload its configuration upon the next logout or reboot.

Then reboot and try the docker commands again.

Comment: for 2nd command i am getting this error systemctl status xorg
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Comment: Enable it as in the answer and start it

Comment: systemctl command not working as i am using docker

Comment: I don't have gdm3 folder in etc

Comment: Install gdm3 first - `apt-get install gdm3`

Comment: after install and uncomment waylandenable=false and when I run dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 I get this error dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 78.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of reload.

Comment: Do you have a desktop environment installed e.g gnome If not install gnome using apt-get install gnome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134971/discussion-between-rahul-and-david-kariuki).

Comment: I used apt-get install dialog and echo exit 0 > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d to bypass the errors and after restarting the container still same error

Comment: Did you install gnome

Comment: yes and gdm3 working fine